# Mouse position not updating while mouse buttons are pressed

Tags: java, mouse

I have a simple mouse manager class: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIcEt.jpg

Whenever any of the mouse buttons are pressed the mouse position does not update when calling `getMouseX()` or `getMouseY()` on the mouse manager object via a basic handler that gets passed everywhere.

Is the problem in my implementation or is it a bug in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your implementation.

Change your button handling code to something like :

```
if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.Button1) {
    leftpressed = true;
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();
}
```

Basically you want to update the stored mouse position on all mouse events.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! Just needed to update the mouse position on `mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)` function in the mouse manager class.